# How can I scrape the text from a certain DIV using PHP and exlude html tags inside the DIV

Tags: php, screen-scraping, scrape

I have a project I'm working on where I need to scrape the text out of a specific div tag but only the text no html tags.

Here is example of the html:

```
<div id="divid1" class="divclass1">
<h1>
TEXT INSIDE DIV
</h1>
</div>
```

I need to scrape the text inside the DIV w/ out the H1 tags.  I've tried this numerous ways and just can't get it right.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, I don't think I was clear in my posting.  I can scrape the text I just can't figure out how to clear the H1 tags.

Answer (score 0):

use PHP domparser, that is good for this purpose.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Answer (score 0):

I would use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

You could say:

```
foreach ($html->find('div[divid1] h1') as $e) 
 echo $e->innertext;
```

This will echo the text within the h1 tag inside #divid1 (but not the tag itself).

The documentation is simple, but helps a bunch: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm